# Flow class generate on tap to icons

Tags: flutter

How do I access the individual Icons within the Flow widget to enable the On Tap?
Below is my code for the Flow widget...I just need to access the individual icons now to actually get them to do something?
thanks

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Flow(
        delegate: FlowMenuDelegate(controller: controller),
        children: <IconData>[
          Icons.menu, //index '0'
          Icons.add_comment, //index '1'
          Icons.add_location, //index '2'
          Icons.alt_route, //index '3'
          Icons.arrow_back,
          Icons.edit,
        ].map<Widget>(buildItem).toList(),
      );

  Widget buildItem(IconData icon) => SizedBox(
        width: buttonSize,
        height: buttonSize,
        child: FloatingActionButton(
          backgroundColor: const Color(0xff324755),
          //shape: const BeveledRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.zero),
          elevation: 0,
          splashColor: Colors.teal,
          child: Icon(icon, color: Colors.white, size: 45),
          onPressed: () {
            if (controller.status == AnimationStatus.completed) {
              controller.reverse();
            } else {
              controller.forward();
            }
          },
        ),
      );
}

class FlowMenuDelegate extends FlowDelegate {
  final Animation<double> controller;
  const FlowMenuDelegate({required this.controller})
      : super(repaint: controller);
```

Comment: Can you include full `FlowMenuDelegate`?

Comment: Hi Yeasin, I just want to know how to use my icons? Do you have any ideas please?

Comment: you can create list<IconData> on state and use it

Comment: again thanks, but as I understand it the IconData list is within the FlowMenuDelegate and I can't work out where I can actually place a GestureDetector for On Tap function. Basically I just want to use this Flow widget and I can't get on with it. Thanks again